# Hiding "Also on Disqus"

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide the bottom half of embedded Disqus comments section on a site using this CSS:

```
#placement-bottom {
display:none !important;
visibility:hidden !important;
}
```

Somehow the CSS is overridden and it still displays.  The section "Also on Disqus") looks super messy and unprofessional as it includes random snippets from irrelevant topics.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the actual markup of your site?

Comment: Disqus is in an `iframe`, yes?  [See here if so.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

css does not apply to the disqus html because it loads as **iFrame**

you can disable the "Also on" box by unchecking the **Settings > Basic > Discovery** checkbox on your Engage Admin page

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
#disqus_thread {
     position: relative;
}
#disqus_thread:after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     height: 55px;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     background: white;
}



</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="disqus_thread">
<script type="text/javascript">
                    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
                    var disqus_shortname = 'xxxxxxx';
                    var disqus_identifier = 'xxxxxx-xxxxx';
                    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
                    (function () {
                        var dsq = document.createElement('script');
                        dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
                        dsq.async = true;
                        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                    })();
                </script>
</body>
</html>
```